# I am using ngx-tooltip within angular-material, but the tooltip is being cut off, any way to adjust z-index?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using ngx-tooltip (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tooltip) with angular.material.io tabs and am running into an issue where the tooltip appears to get cut off on the left side when inside of the md-tab container. How do I make it such that the tooltip floats above everything? Is there some way I can adjust the z-index of the tooltip or is there some other way?

Code:

```
<md-tab-group>
<md-tab label="Tab 1">
    <!-- tooltip with dynamic html content -->
    <div>
        <tooltip-content #myTooltip>
            <b>Very</b> <span style="color: #C21F39">Dynamic</span> <span style="color: #00b3ee">Reusable</span> 
            <b><i><span style="color: #ffc520">Tooltip With</span></i></b> <small>Html support</small>.
        </tooltip-content>

        <button [tooltip]="myTooltip">hover this button to see a tooltip</button>
    </div>

</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Comment: It's hard to say something without code... Post some code and (maybe) a plunker that reproduces the problem. Also, doesn't md-tooltip fill your requirements?

Comment: md-tooltip doesn't have flexibility of HTML template with custom colors/styling... (unless I am missing something). I am using the example that is similar to here for ngx-tooltip. Updated OP with code.

Comment: @Rolando can you provide a working fiddle which support this

Comment: You could set the CSS attribute `overflow: visible` on the parent containers of the tooltip to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Tried that looks like it's still hiding behind the parent container...

Comment: @Rolando I had the same issue with ngx-tooltip where tooltip hides behind parent element or tab and doesn't flip based on the cursor position. My two cents on this issue, the tooltip has to be placed and attached to the body element, it should not be available inside the angular component.    I am using the following tooltip which is attached the tooltip to the body of the HTML, works fine and flips based on the cursor position. URL link https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-ui/#tooltip  and github link https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-ui/tree/master/src/components/tooltip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced your problem in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DhrkpRo8WqmH18b7tWk3?p=preview). In order to make the tooltip visible outside of the md-tab container, I had to do the following (see [this corrected plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xBEz4RLyuX1FnGfDHz5G?p=preview)):

1. In the Component decorator, I set the encapsulation to `ViewEncapsulation.None`:

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  styleUrls: ["./tabs-overview-example.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

2. In the CSS file, I set the `overflow` attribute as follows:

```
md-tab-group,
md-tab-body,
.mat-tab-body-wrapper,
.mat-tab-body-content
{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: did the same thing and it's still not working :(

Comment: This fixed it for me: .mat-tab-body {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `#myTooltip` is the reference to your tooltip, in your component

```
import {Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() myTooltip: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.myTooltip.nativeElement.style.zIndex = '9999 !important';
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with this is if I have say 20 tooltips, so I dynamically use "ngFor" to create them, how can I dynamically link those ElementRefs to #myTooltip1,#myTooltip3,#myTooltip4? How would I even ngFor create those?

Comment: Other problem is I have 2 tabs, so on initialization, the tooltip is not shown, until the user switches to the 2nd tab.

Comment: You just have to give them a class, let's say `top-z-tooltip`, where you set the z-index to 9999.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to add ".mat-tab-body" for it to work:

```
md-tab-group,
md-tab-body,
.mat-tab-body-wrapper,
.mat-tab-body-content, 
.mat-tab-body
{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```